# Prove that the 8 vectors from the center to the vertices sum is 0

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a cube in space with vertices $v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_8 \in \mathbb R^3$ and center $c \in \mathbb R^3$.

Prove that the eight vectors from the center to the vertices sum to the zero vector $0 = (0; 0; 0)$ in space, i.e.

$\vec{cv_1} +\vec{cv_2} +...+\vec{cv_8} =0$

If you draw an eight dimension shape and point a center and connect all the corners, you will have a visual view of the question. Is it zero vector because its symmetric?

Comment: Yes, the symmetry is essential here. In particular, [*point symmetry*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_reflection) with respect to the center of the cube. I'm not sure what you're looking for as an answer though...

Comment: @John I noticed the latest edit you made - and it seemed to be to "scramble" the question. This is unacceptable, and I have rolled back the edit as well as flagged the post.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's because of symmetry. That works every time you have one or more geometric transformations carrying your set of vectors into itself and such that every point in space (apart from the center) is changed under some transformation. If the sum $\vec{s}$ of the vectors were not vanishing, then $\vec{s}$ would be changed into $\vec{s}'\ne\vec{s}$ under some transformation, while the vectors would be left unaltered. So your set of vectors would have two different sums, which is absurd. Hence it must be $\vec{s}=0$.

Some examples. In the case of a figure having central symmetry (as for your cube) this is enough, because a point reflection around the center leaves only the center fixed. A generic regular pyramid has only a rotational symmetry around its axis, so you can only infer that the sum of vectors must have the direction of this axis. But for the special case of a regular tetrahedron there are four rotational symmetries of 120° around four different axes, so that the above reasoning applies and the sum of vectors must vanish.

Comment: can you prove that?

Comment: Ahem… my answer was in fact a proof. What is not clear to you?

Comment: oh right, thanks aretino! i got confused because i was expecting a proof in a mathematical way(like not wording) if you know what i mean

Comment: I've edited my answer to render it more comprehensible, at least I hope so.